# recursive number generator not working

Tags: python, list, recursion

I'm currently learning python, and while trying to write a simple lotto program, I came across a little problem.

I'm trying to do is generate two lists, each containing six numbers. the first one is generatedby asking the user for a number.

The second one generates random integers between 1 and 49 by using `randint`

If I code it like this:

```
from random import randint

lottoschein = []
gewinnzahlen = []

while (len(lottoschein)<6):
  lottoschein.append(int(input("Bitte geben sie eine Zahl ein: ")))# Eingabeaufforderung
  print (lottoschein)
  print (len(lottoschein))


while (len(gewinnzahlen)<6):
   zahl = randint (1,49)
   gewinnzahlen.append(zahl)
   print (gewinnzahlen)
```

It actually works and generates a nice output like

```
Bitte geben sie eine Zahl ein: 1
[1]
1
Bitte geben sie eine Zahl ein: 5
[1, 5]
2
Bitte geben sie eine Zahl ein: 4
[1, 5, 4]
3
Bitte geben sie eine Zahl ein: 4
[1, 5, 4, 4]
4
Bitte geben sie eine Zahl ein: 5
[1, 5, 4, 4, 5]
5
Bitte geben sie eine Zahl ein: 8
[1, 5, 4, 4, 5, 8]
6
[40]
[40, 33]
[40, 33, 42]
[40, 33, 42, 20]
[40, 33, 42, 20, 35]
[40, 33, 42, 20, 35, 14]
```

Just what I asked it to do.
But if I try coding it in a recursive function like this:

```
from random import randint

lottoschein = []
gewinnzahlen = []

def zahlen (schein,zahl):
  if(len(schein)<6):
   schein.append(zahl)
   return zahlen (schein,zahl)
  else:
    print (schein)
    return schein

lottoschein = zahlen (lottoschein, int(input("Bitte geben sie eine Zahl ein: ")))
gewinnzahlen = zahlen (gewinnzahlen, randint (1,49))
```

it returns an output like:

```
Bitte geben sie eine Zahl ein: 2
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
[17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17]
```

seems like it generates the numbers only once.
What I don't understand is why. Could anyone help me get the recursive function working please?

Comment: you're asking for the number only once! `input("Bitte geben Sie eine Zahl ein")` happens only once. You might want to move that piece of code inside your `zahlen` function.

Comment: i cant use the input inside of my zahlen function beause then i would need 2 functions. One for the manual input the other for the automatic generation. that would make the functional programming compleetly useless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you call `randint()`, it returns a number. It is *that number* that is passed into the function, not the function.

In other words, you only call the function *once* and reuse the output, over and over again.

Your `while` loops, on the other hand, re-execute the loop body each iteration, so in that case the `input()` function or `randint()` function is called for each iteration of the `while` loop and thus input a new number.

If you wanted a function called each time you go through the loop, pass in the function and arguments instead:

```
def zahlen(schein, function, *arguments):
    if len(schein) < 6:
        schein.append(function(*arguments))
        return zahlen(schein, function, *arguments)
    return schein
```

and call this with:

```
lottoschein = zahlen(lottoschein, lambda: int(input("Bitte geben sie eine Zahl ein: "))))
gewinnzahlen = zahlen(gewinnzahlen, randint, 1, 49)
```

Now either `lambda: int(input('....'))` (with no arguments) is called each time in the recursive function, or `randint` is called with the arguments `1` and `49`.

Demo:

```
>>> def zahlen(schein, function, *arguments):
...     if len(schein) < 6:
...         schein.append(function(*arguments))
...         return zahlen(schein, function, *arguments)
...     return schein
... 
>>> from random import randint
>>> zahlen([], randint, 1, 49)
[42, 11, 41, 28, 27, 24]
>>> zahlen([], lambda: int(input('Please enter a number: ')))
Please enter a number: 10
Please enter a number: 20
Please enter a number: 30
Please enter a number: 42
Please enter a number: 38
Please enter a number: 2
[10, 20, 30, 42, 38, 2]
```

Comment: Well if i try it that way i only get SyntaxError: can use starred expression only as assignment target

Comment: @Sulumar: did you use the function exactly as shown here? What version of Python are you using? I tested this with both Python 2.7 and 3.3.

Comment: My Bad works like a charm thx. now i just have to understand a few details

Comment: Normally the gewinnzahlen has to consist of unique numbers. so it might be better to make `schein` a `set` instead of a list (and use `schein.add` instead of `append`...)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the line

```
   return zahlen (schein,zahl)
```

Here, you are calling `zahlen` with the same integer `zahl` that was used on the first call. Try to replace it with:

```
return zahlen(schein, int(input("Bitte geben sie eine Zahl ein: ")))
```